# random numbers generation from 0 to 0.5

Tags: matlab

can we generate random numbers for floating point numbers if I use this function it is showing

```
randi([0 0.5])
```

Error using randi
First input must be a positive scalar integer value IMAX, or two integer values [IMIN IMAX] with
IMIN less than or equal to IMAX.

is there any solution or we should write our own code for random numbers generation

Comment: Why not just get a random number in the range `[0,1]` and halve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`r = rand(n)` returns an n-by-n matrix containing pseudorandom values drawn from the standard uniform distribution on the open interval (0,1).

just use `rand*0.5` to get the random # between 0 and 0.5.

Comment: if it is for 0.5 to 1 then with value we should multiply

Comment: @user2490712 `(max - min)*r + min` The factor determines the “width” of possible values, the addition translates this range to the correct position. If `min=0.5` and `max=1`, then this becomes `0.5*r + 0.5`. Do note that due to floating-point operations, precision may be lost. Changing the range from *[0.5, 1]* to *[min, max]* reduces the number of possible random values in that range.

Comment: @amon Awesome :) I like (max - min)*r + min

Answer (score 0):

I find the as another solution.

```
import random
val = random.randint(0,5)/10
```

Another simplified answer would be:

```
val = random.uniform(0, 0.5)
```